# Run Perl Editor in SSIS via Execute Process Task

Tags: perl, ssis

I'm a newbie to SSIS and working my way through (hopefully) automating some daily tasks.

I've configured an Execute Process Task to run a Perl editor with a script as the argument.  My issue is that it only opens the program but does not run (F5).  What is the procedure for making the program run on its own without any manual intervention?  Am I using the right task for the job?

Comment: why not write the script in C# and use an execute script task?

Comment: You have the correct task, but I question whether you have the right target. Execute Process Task will allow you to run whatever .exe you want. However, SSIS is really designed to be something that runs unattended so running an editor as your target seems questionable. I would think your target should really be a perl interpreter (the thing that *goes* when you hit F5).

Comment: HLGEM - We have a C# expert in-house so I can ask them about what the code will need to look like and try it out via Script Task.

Comment: billinkc - I absolutely want to run this unattended and perhaps I picked the wrong target.  I'm not sure I know the difference between the editor .exe and the interpreter .exe(?), which is probably the source of my issue.  Running a Perl script outside of an editor seems foreign and am unsure how to approach it.

Comment: Either way, thanks to both for suggestions on completely different approaches to the same task.

Comment: @billinkc: worked like a charm.  got the right exe and off i go.  thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [Execute Process Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141166.aspx), ensure that you are referencing the perl interpreter and not an editor. Assuming an ActiveState's ActivePerl install, the interpreter would be either

- C:\Perl\perl.exe
- C:\Perl64\perl.exe